# Timer_ConnectionIdle in HttpErr

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have a web service application with some reliability issues I am trying to diagnose.

One thing that I noticed is that there are a number of entries in the HTTPERR log that indicate "Timer_ConnectionIdle".  I have read a few places that these are innocent and occur when the client leaves a connection open and then doesn't get around to reusing it before the server times out.

I'm wondering however if it could also be happening if my server-side application is taking too long to respond to requests.

I guess my question is whether a Timer_ConnectionIdle event is triggered if the server application doesn't start writing a response to the client within the 2-minute default timeout window or if the "clock" is only ticking when the application is not working on servicing the request.

Answer (score 1):

No - the Time_ConnectionIdle event really is benign.

If your application takes too long to respond, it will show up in your normal HTTP log as a 500 error.